# The curvature of a tangent to a curve considered as a curve in its own right

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

Suppose we have a curve $c:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ that is parametrised with respect to arc length. We then consider $T,B,N$ (tangent, binormal and normal) as curve in there own right each defined at a time $t$. The task is to express the curvature of the curve $T$ in terms of the curvature and torsion of the orginal curve $c$. I am struggling to do this. So far I have:

$$
\begin{align*}
\kappa_T &= \frac{\|T' \times T''\|}{\|T'\|^3} \\
&=\frac{\|T' \times T''\|}{\kappa^3}\\
&=\frac{\|c'' \times c'''\|}{\kappa^3}.
\end{align*}
$$

I need a expression for that top product, I am trying to link it to the alternative formula for torsion given by:
$$
\tau = \frac{\det(c'(t),c''(t),c'''(t)}{\|c' \times c''\|^2}.
$$

Any help welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have it now:

We can rewrite the numerator of the torsion formula in the following way
$
\tau = \frac{det(c'(t),c''(t),c'''(t)}{||c' \times c''||^2}
= \frac{c'\cdot (c'' \times c''')}{||c' \times c''||^2}
$
Now we use that the denominator is actually $\kappa^2$, multiply up and take norms of both sides:

$
||\tau \kappa^2|| = ||c'||||c'' \times c'''||\
= ||c'' \times c'''||
$

And substituting this into what I had earlier, I get:

$
\kappa_T = \frac{||\tau||}{\kappa}
$

Comment: I am afraid this answer is wrong. The norm of the inner product $c'\cdot (c''\times c''')$ is not equal to $\|c'\| \|c''\times c'''\|$. I have added the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, denote the curve given by the tangent $T$ by $\gamma$. We will express $\gamma'$ and $\gamma''$ in term of the Frenet frame $T$, $N$, $B$ of $c$.
We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\gamma' &= \kappa N  \\
\gamma'' &= -\kappa^2 T + \kappa' N + \kappa \tau B\\
\gamma' \times \gamma'' &= \kappa (-\kappa^2 N \times T + \kappa \tau N\times B) \\
              &= \kappa^2 (\tau T + \kappa B).
\end{align*}
$$

So the curvature $\kappa_\gamma$ of the curve $\gamma=T$ becomes
$$
\begin{align*}
 \kappa_\gamma&= \frac{\|\gamma' \times \gamma''\|}{\|\gamma'\|^3} \\
          &= \frac{\kappa^2 \sqrt{\tau^2 + \kappa^2}}{\kappa^3} \\
          &= \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\tau}{\kappa}\right)^2}.
\end{align*}
$$